# How Do I mix colors using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a box with two colors with silver on top and it should slowly fade into white, just as Apple's homepage background. How do i do that?

Thanks as always.

Comment: Heres a friendly advice to you if you don't mind. Please accept a question. Be beneficial to people who help you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use CSS3 here's a great example: http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/

W/o CSS3, you have to make do with an image repeated horizontally (x-repeat), similar to what tvanfosson said.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for gradient background?

http://www.tizag.com/cssT/background.php

look for "css gradient background"

there are more articles if you google: gradient background css

Comment: Note that background gradients work in all modern browsers, and that IE has had a way to do this for a long time now. To make it easier for you, try using the ColorZilla Gradient Generator, which creates the Webkit, Mozilla and IE filter versions for you in much the same way as the Photoshop gradient editor does its thing: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to use a background image that does the gradient for you.  You sent the background color of the page to the "end" color of the gradient, then apply your gradient background image using CSS with a repeat in the opposite direction that you want the gradient to flow.  So if you want a 100-pixel, silver to white, gradient from top to bottom you'd create a 100Hx1W pixel image that spans your colors from top to bottom.  Set the background color to white and apply the background image repeating across the x axis.  You can easily create the gradient using the gradient tool in Photoshop or GIMP.

```
#body
{
   background: #ffffff url(/images/bg.jpg) repeat-x;
}
```